# redirect a subdirectory to another domain in lighttpd

Tags: redirect, lighttpd

I am trying to redirect a subdirectory to a different domain, ideally https.  I have some redirect rule in place to forward to http to https and its working but I want one particular subdirectory to forward to another domain.   And it should forward example.com/subdir/whatever to  newdomain.com/whatever

```
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "example.com" {
    accesslog.filename         = "/var/log/lighttpd/example.com/access.log"
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://example.com/$1" )
    server.name                 = "example.com"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the documentation? https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModRedirect

```
url.redirect = (
  "^/subdir/whatever/(.*)" => "https://newdomain.com/whatever/$1",
  "^/(.*)" => "https://example.com/$1"
)
```